# connect epic games account with github

Tags: github, unreal-engine4

I want to get the unreal engine source from github. I followed the steps on [unreal engine 4 on github](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github), I created an epic games account. After that I need to associate that account with my github account. After step 5 "After opening the **Connected Accounts** menu, select the **Connect** button below the GitHub icon", I got this:

[image: connect epic games account with github]

The problem is, clicking the "Authorize EpicGames" in the light green part did nothing. I don't know where the problem is and I cannot proceed. Anyone have encountered this?
One reasonable explanation is network problem. I mean if there are some problems with some servers, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Now I know the answer.
Github page warns that "Please note that Github no longer supports your web browser".

[image: github]

But I ignored it before.
So using my latest firefox or updating the outdated chrome which I was using to the latest version solved my problem.

Comment: Browser compatibility: well spotted. +1

Answer (score 0):

https://status.epicgames.com/ reports:

> ### Jul 18, 2018 Matchmaking issues
>
> Resolved - The issues impacting matchmaking have been addressed and we're seeing full recovery. Jul 18, 00:49 UTC

It is possible there are still lingering effects of incidents on epicgames side.